# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why do I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'" in the following SQL?:

```
use AdventureWorks
CREATE FUNCTION Query2_Function(@DPT INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
IF @DPT is not null
select edh.departmentid,d.name,count(*)as cnt 
    From HumanResources.Employee e
    inner join HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh on e.employeeID = edh.employeeid
    inner join humanresources.department d on edh.departmentid = d.departmentid
    where d.Name = @dpt
    group by edh.departmentid, d.name
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have any flow of control statements in inline table valued functions. If `@dpt is null` the query will return an empty result set anyway

Edit: or at least would if the correct datatype. You have `@DPT INT` and are comparing against a `name` column. That seems doomed to failure at execution time.

Edit 2:

As a solution, you could 1) simply drop the `IF @DPT is not null` line and 2) either

- change the `@DPT` parameter's type from `INT` to something like `varchar(100)`, if the function was supposed to search for the department by name,

or

- change the `WHERE` clause to something like this:

  ```
  where d.departmentid = @dpt
  ```

  if you meant it to search by department ID.

Comment: Oh it's nothing, really. I figured, if I posted that separately, my answer would look incomplete, unless I chose to repeat all your points with dull remarks like *'Just like Martin pointed out...'*.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Query2_Function(@DPT INT)
RETURNS  @tbl TABLE 
   (
    departmentid    int  ,   
    [name]      varchar(100),
    cnt int          
   )
AS

begin

IF @DPT is not null
insert into @tbl (departmentid,name,cnt)
select edh.departmentid,d.name,count(*)as cnt 
    From HumanResources.Employee e
    inner join HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh on e.employeeID = edh.employeeid
    inner join humanresources.department d on edh.departmentid = d.departmentid
    where d.DepartmentID =@DPT 
    group by edh.departmentid, d.name
return  
 end

GO
```